# Unable to connect to Mongo with NestJS + Mongoose on Openshift

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, openshift

I’m trying to deploy a NestJS service that connects to a Mongo instance using Mongoose.

I’m able to get the connection from VS Code, from a container hosted on my machine and from a devcontainer, but not from Openshift.

Looking at Mongo logs, the pod connects correctly to the database but immediately it closes the connection with the following error:

2023-11-17T10:40:51.202+0100 D NETWORK  [conn134] Session from 172.24.225.46:36908 encountered a network error during SourceMessage
2023-11-17T10:40:51.202+0100 I NETWORK  [conn134] end connection 172.24.225.46:36908 (122 connections now open)

It’s like the database try to send back to the client a feedback of the successful connection, but can’t reach the pod. From the pod terminal I can telnet the database 27017 port and I can query a collection with mongosh client. I get the error only from Openshift using mongoose.